# Why are PDEs and in particular dispersive PDEs considered on $S^1$ so often?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have seen many PDE people work on the circle. It seems like such a common domain, sometimes even more common than on $\Bbb{R}$. Why? Does it just mean "some interval"? Why not just say an interval?

Comment: $S^1$ typically denotes the circle, not the torus.

Comment: @GuyPaterson-Jones Of course a 1 dimensional torus is just a circle. :) But because you asked so nicely I'll change it to circle.

Comment: @GuyPaterson-Jones see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#n-dimensional_torus

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I'm stuck in 2-dimensional land when it comes to torii =P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply a convenient way of saying that one is working on an interval *with periodic boundary conditions*.